# Return single row in an EF-generated class with its children set ordered in LinqToSql (c#)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by

I would like to make a simple operation with **LinqToSql** but I cannot find the right way. I have the following tables, hereby represented with an **EF-generated** class diagram:

[image: EF-generated class diagram]

Where the foreign key relationship is on **SessionId** (primary key table **WebinarSession**).

I want to make a query that returns *1* **WebinarSession** with its corresponding  children on **WebinarTopic**, **ORDERED** by **TopicStartTime**.

Taking into account that **_webinarRecordingsDB** is the repository object, I already tried the solutions that looked more logic to me:

```
WebinarSession lsession = _webinarRecordingsDB.WebinarTopics
    .OrderBy(m => m.TopicStartTime)
    .Select(m => m.WebinarSession)
    .Single(m => m.SessionId == sessionId);

WebinarSession lsession = _webinarRecordingsDB.WebinarSessions
    .Single(m => m.SessionId == sessionId).WebinarTopics
    .OrderBy(m => m.TopicStartTime)
    .Single(m => m.WebinarSession.SessionId == sessionId);
```

Those launch an exception because they find more rows in WebinarSession. As last (illogical) resort I also tried:

```
WebinarSession lsession = _webinarRecordingsDB.WebinarSessions
    .Single(m => m.SessionId == sessionId);

lsession.WebinarTopics.OrderBy(m => m.TopicStartTime);
```

that does not launch any exception but does not perfor the sorting on lsession. Anybody might help me please? Thanks

**EDIT**

I want to keep the result in a **WebinarSession** object

Answer (score 2):

The Second Option is close, but you have to assign the sorted WebinarTopics back to a new IList or something, such as the following...

```
WebinarSession lsession = _webinarRecordingsDB.WebinarSessions.Single(m => m.SessionId == sessionId);
List<WebinarTopic> ltopics = lsession.WebinarTopics.OrderBy(m => m.TopicStartTime).ToList();
```

HTH.
Dave

Comment: thanks for your answer. The second assignment however will not work because you are trying to put in a WebinarSession a set of WebinarTopic objects. It will give a compile-time error

Comment: Right you are - was not thinking straight - have amended my answer to correct

Comment: The problem is that I want to keep everything inside a WebinarSession variable because otherwise I have to change most parts of the applications. In your case you have the ordered set stored in WebinarTopic colletion

Answer (score 2):

The `OrderBy` extension method does not does change the collection, but returns a new (ordered) collection. You need to store the results in a variable and use that:

```
var session = _webinarRecordingsDB.WebinarSessions
    .Single(m => m.SessionId == sessionId);

var topics = session.WebinarTopics.OrderBy(m => m.TopicStartTime);
```

Comment: @Steven: thanks for the answer. I want to keep everything inside a WebinarSession variable because otherwise I have to change most parts of the applications.

Comment: @Francesco: What you want is not possible. The `WebinarSession` class contains a `WebinarTopics` property of type `EntitySet<WebinarTopic>`. The `EntitySet<T>` is a LINQ to SQL specific type. It is not possible to change the order in which those items appear.

Comment: @Francesco: I would say it is time to rethink your architecture.

Comment: @Steven: what you are saying is that with LinqToSql I cannot order the content of a table by using the navigation properties? That seems quite resctrictive for a powerfool technology such LinqToSql...

Comment: @Francesco: What do you mean by 'navigation properties'? The order in which items are returned is unknown and may change over time, simple because LINQ to SQL returns the items in the same order as it gets it from SQL Server and that's the way it works in databases. All the O/RM tools I know have this exact same behavior. Ordering is not the concern of LINQ to SQL; it the concern of the application developer.

Comment: @Steven: For navigation property I mean that property created by the EF in a table/object that allows to navigate to another table/object if between the two there is a foreign key relationship, as it happens for my WebinarSession and WebinarTopic tables/objects linked by a 1 to many relationship. For each WebinarSession row corresponds many WebinarTopic rows. My only purpose is to have back a specific WebinarSession row/object and order the corresponding (WebinarSession.SessionId == WebinarTopic.SessionId) WebinarTopic row collection.